# What published adventures are officially set in Westeros?

Tags: published-adventures, d20-system, song-of-ice-and-fire-rpg, a-game-of-thrones-d20

I'm looking adventures set in Westeros. I know there are at least two role-playing games set in the world of *A Song of Ice and Fire*: *A Game of Thrones* by Guardians of Order and *A Song of Ice and Fire Roleplaying* by Green Ronin, but what adventures are available for these games?

I found the introductory adventure *In Bounds of Blood and Honour*, and in that there's an ad for a *Winter Is Coming* scenario trilogy (about House Flint) from Sword & Sorcery Studios and Guardians of Order, but more information is unavailable. Was this trilogy published?

Besides *In Bounds*, *Troubles in Pembroke* and *Wedding Knight*, what other adventures are available? They may help me, but my question is mainly concerned about *Winter is Coming* trilogy.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the ones you already cited, there are also these two Adventure modules for SIFRP (these links point at the Green Ronin Store):

[Perils at King's Landing](http://greenroninstore.com/collections/a-song-of-ice-and-fire-roleplaying/products/peril-at-kings-landing-pdf) 
[Dragon's Hoard](http://greenroninstore.com/collections/a-song-of-ice-and-fire-roleplaying/products/dragons-hoard-a-song-of-ice-and-fire-pdf)

Unfortunately, I don't know a lot about the Guardians of Order game, but I hope that these two for SIFRP can help you.

EDIT:
I was researching a bit around the net, and I found very little useful information. Probably, since the "rebirth" of White Wolf (the company that owned Sword & Sorcery) and the aggressive campaign of regaining control over their products (like the World of Darkness), a lot of stuff from the GoO works are been taken down.
I found that in **Dragon Magazine #307** there are a bit of resources (eg: Tyrion Lannister characteristics), but unfortunately I didn't found anything else. :/

Comment: Thank you very much! However the main part of my question is concerned about Guardians Trilogy :( I really hope someone heard about it :(

Comment: I made a bit of research in the net, and edited the answer. Maybe you can find something else.